# Offset of <a> tag , is off by few pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to create a simple dotted underline animation for a menu bar of mine , so i wrote the following HTML:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navigation">

  <ul class="nav-listed-links">
    <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Our Potfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact US</a></li>
    <li class="underline"></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

And the following JS code to make the underline move.

JS:

```
$('.nav-listed-links > li > a').hover(function() {

  var offset = ($(this).offset().left - 0),
    width = $(this).outerWidth();

  $('.underline').addClass('on');

  $('.underline').css({
    left: offset,
    width: width
  });

}, function() {

  $('.underline').removeClass('on');


});
```

The smooth animation is CSS transitions, **[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/w8unr0od/1/)**.

Ok so now lets zero down on the problem , In the JS code i am try to get how far off the `<a>` is from the left of the document and so i have the following code:

```
var offset = ($(this).offset().left - 0)
```

Yet the underline is a bit off from where the start of the `<a>` tag is, see screenshot below:

[image: BUG]

Why is this happening. I am sure this is something silly , but i really have't been able to figure this out for the life in me.

Comment: @pmahomme more interested in the `WHY` part rather then the solution :) TY though

Comment: I see that @Rohit figured it out a few minutes ago... it's the margin of the body defaulting at 8px: https://jsfiddle.net/seLLz177/.  When set to 0 it's fine.  Using Chrome's "Inspect Element" or Firefox has something similar is a very helpful way to figure things like this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `offset()` you

> retrieves the current position relative to the document

Therefore with the default `margin` of the `body` you have that extra gap.

I suggest the use of `position()` to avoid any problems, since the underline is relative to the `ul` container :

> retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent

```
var offset = $(this).position().left,
```

---

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/w8unr0od/4/)

---

<sub>[Reference Position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

This is just because of the `margin`, the `body` have in the fiddle. Setting `margin: 0` works perfect. Such `margin` you might be having on the outer elements also. You'll have to take those margins also.

Here is an updated JSFiddle with `margin-left: 0px;` on the body element: https://jsfiddle.net/w8unr0od/2/